# How to trigger a Jenkins build from XRay jira?

Tags: jenkins, jira-xray

I am trying to trigger a build in Jenkins directly from Xray. I have been successfully able to create a trigger in jira and has provided the webhook url and other information needed to run the build. But on triggering the build from any Test Plan, I am getting the following error:
Error publishing web request. Response HTTP status:503
ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved.

When i'm hitting the same webhook url in any browser, then the build is getting triggered in jenkins, hence it seems there's no issue with the provided webhook url.
One thing to note is that our Xray is in Jira cloud whereas the Jenkins is running behind a VPN. Can anyone help me in resolving the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your Xray on Jira Cloud is trying to acess Jenkins, the Jenkins server needs to have a public URL. If you have it behind the firewall then it's not possible for Xray or any other tool to trigger it directly.
You can call the Jenkins URL from your browser because you are probably with your vpn connected.
The possible workaround would be to use a tool such as ngrok, as [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Taking+advantage+of+Jira+Cloud+built-in+automation+capabilities#TakingadvantageofJiraCloudbuiltinautomationcapabilities-Tips), to make a tunnel, but beware with the security implications of exposing your Jenkins url to the world.

For reference, Xray cloud provides [documentation/examples](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Taking+advantage+of+Jira+Cloud+built-in+automation+capabilities#TakingadvantageofJiraCloudbuiltinautomationcapabilities-Jenkins) showcasing how to take advantage of Jira Cloud automation capabilities to trigger jobs, for example in Jenkins.